# How to extract a log of "edit sizes" from a subversion repository

Tags: svn

I have a Subversion repository, and I would like to extract detailed information about the history of who edited what and when and how. I know I can run `svn log --xml` to produce a nice easy-to-use record of which paths were altered in each revision. But what I would also like to find out is the size of the edits to each file.

I know there are many ways to define "edit distance", but I will be happy with anything simple like "number of lines that are different" for text files.

Presumably I can get all this by parsing the output of `svnadmin dump`, but then I'd need to spend time learning about the dump file format, which I'd rather avoid if I can.

Comment: For what purpose would you like to do this?

Comment: May be a tool like statsvn might be for you?

Comment: I want to develop a visualisation, to show which users are "big heavy change" users and which are "many light touches" users. statsvn is no use, since it only works with the "svn log" output, and I want more data than is contained there.

Comment: If you really like to extract the information about what has changed there is no other way than getting the information about every file. How else would you like to read the size of edits...cause you are talking about the deltas which have been stored in the repository. May if you try to access the repository native without svn client...But this isn't very simple...I've written a search engine for SVN Repositories which is very fast....and i read all files...plus their contents and type etc. So i don't see a real problem their...

Comment: What size of repositories do you expect? How many revisions? And what time do you have time to do the job?

Comment: As I said in my question, I know that I can use "svnadmin dump" to find exactly what all the edits were, but that would require me to spend time learning about the dump format. I asked the question to find out if there is a shortcut. It's for fun, not work, and learning about the dump format sounds like work not fun.

Comment: The repository in question has 2313 files and 1173 revisions, amounting to 3482 M/A/D/R records, of which 1141 are M records.

Comment: I'm indexing a repository of 30 GiB size with ca. 1.000.000 Revision in about nine hours...so it shouldn't be real problem..I index every file in the repository...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The svn dump format, it turns out, is very easy to parse. If I generate it with `svnadmin dump --deltas` then the dump file contains deltas for each file modification, and I can reasonably take the size of the delta (in bytes) to be the edit distance.

In case anyone comes looking here, here is a simple Python script which takes an svn dump file and prints out an XML file containing all the properties. The edit sizes are contained in `//path/Text-content-length` entries.

```
def read_defs(f):
    res = {}
    while True:
        l = f.readline()
        if l in ['','\n']: break
        s = l.split(': ',1)
        if len(s)!=2: assert False, 'Bad definition line '+l
        res[s[0]] = (s[1][:-1] if s[1].endswith('\n') else s[1])
    if len(res)==0 and l=='': return None
    return res

def read_props(f):
    res = {}
    lastkey = None
    while True:
        l = f.readline()
        if l.startswith('PROPS-END'): break
        ln = int(l.split()[1])
        l2 = f.read(ln); f.readline()
        if l.startswith('K'):
            lastkey = l2; res[l2] = None
        elif l.startswith('V'):
            res[lastkey] = l2
        else:
            assert False, 'Unexpected prop entry '+l
    return res

def parsedump(f):
        print '<?xml version="1.0"?>'
        print '<log>'
        inrevision,inpaths = False,False
        while True:
            d = read_defs(f)
            if d is None: break
            p = read_props(f) if 'Prop-content-length' in d else {}
            if 'Revision-number' in d:
                if inpaths: print '</paths>'; inpaths=False
                if inrevision: print '</logentry>'
                print '<logentry revision="'+d['Revision-number']+'">'
                inrevision = True
                for k,v in p.iteritems(): print '<'+k+'>'+v+'</'+k+'>'
            elif 'Node-path' in d:
                if not inpaths: print '<paths>'; inpaths=True
                print '<path>'
                for k,v in d.iteritems(): print '<'+k+'>'+v+'</'+k+'>'
                for k,v in p.iteritems(): print '<'+k+'>'+v+'</'+k+'>'
                print '</path>'
            cl = (int(d['Content-length']) if 'Content-length' in d else 0)
            pcl = (int(d['Prop-content-length']) if 'Prop-content-length' in d else 0)
            f.seek(cl-pcl,1)
        if inpaths: print '</paths>'
        if inrevision: print '</logentry>'
        print '</log>'

import sys
if __name__=='__main__':
    if len(sys.argv)==0:
        print 'Usage: svndump2xml FILENAME\nConverts FILENAME to xml, and prints to standard output'
        sys.exit(0)
    filename = sys.argv[1]
    with open(filename,'rb') as f:
        parsedump(f)
```

Answer (score 0):

What you can use for this:

```
  svn blame -r10:10 URL/file.java
```

This will printout the lines which have been changed in that particular changeset which you can use to extract such information but this is only an approximation not exactly.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. But to use this for my purpose I'd need to read the svn log, then issue "svn blame" queries for every time any file changes, which would be a lot of repository accesses, and probably rather slow.